# Python: Include / copy in lines from other script?

Tags: python, parsing, file-io, import, ironpython

Consider y.py:

```
def f():
    x = 1
    y = 2
```

And x.py:

```
from y import f
    f()
    a = x + 1
    b = y + 1
```

Obviously x.py won't work, since y.f() is not returning anything. So how do I handle the case where I want to copy in multiple lines from one script into some pre-determined point in another script, ultimately resutling in x.py looking like the following before it gets executed?

```
x = 1
y = 2
a = x + 1
b = y + 1
```

Note that this simple example contains just variable declarations. In actuality y.py will contain a mixture of variable declarations, flow control, classes, functions etc.

Many thanks for your helpfulness.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to reconsider your program structure. You could possibly make this work via use of `execfile`, but it would be horrible. Python has namespaces and classes for a reason: you should use them.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is inlining mechanism, a macro. Python doesn't have those and for good reasons. What you're asking for most surely can be done with existing Python constructs, like functions or classes. You need to provide more of your code if we are to help.

Based on your basic example, think about how can you refactor your code from "f" function, so that "x" and "y" are separate functions (instead of local variables) that can be called independently, and that you can use in your "x.py" program. Lots of local variables is a code smell, so I would start at refactoring that into more manageable and independent elements.